# Point closest to a line defined by a combination of 2 vectors - prove that it is perpendicular

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $a$ and $b$ are two *different* $n$-vectors, and a vector $x$, I was able to find a point $p$ on the line defined as $(1 - \theta)a + \theta b$. It's coordinates are given by:

$$\left(1 - \frac{(a-x)(a-b)}{(a - b)^2}\right)a + \left(\frac{(a-x)(a-b)}{(a - b)^2}\right)b$$

The exercise I am trying to solve then asks to prove that $(p-x)\bot(a-b)$.

I'm quite stuck on this point. Is there a clever "shortcut" to show the vectors $p-x$ and $a -b$ are perpendicular, without "brute-forcing" it, that is taking dot product of vectors to show it is equal to zero? Multiplication gets very tedious, and I am not sure if this was the point of the exercise.

Comment: (1) If $a$ and $b$ are vectors, how do you multiply them or even divide something by them? (2) What is the role of $x$ in your setting? Are you trying to find the point $p$ on the line joining $a$ and $b$ which is closest to $x$?

Comment: (1) I think $(a-b)^2$ is a scalar, so I was able to divide by it (2) Yes, $x$ is a completely arbitrary point/vector in that space. The first part of the exercise was to find the point $p$ on the line crossing points $a$ and $b$, which is closest to $x$. The second part (one that I have troubles with) asks to prove that that vector $(p-x)$ is perpendicular to that line.

Comment: (1) I guess you are actually considering inner product, i.e., $(a-b)\cdot(a-b)$.

Comment: (1) Yes, it's a dot product. I'm not sure about the proper notation - the book I am working through usually skips $\cdot$ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$ \alpha(\theta) = (1-\theta)a + \theta b
\quad \text{and} \quad 
f(\theta) = (\alpha(\theta) - x) \cdot (\alpha(\theta) - x). $$

Then $f(\theta)$ is the square-distance between $x$ and $\alpha(\theta)$. Also, let $\theta_0$ denote the minimum point of $f$. Since minimizing distance is equivalent to minimizing square-distance, it follows that $p = \alpha(\theta_0)$. Also, we must have [$f'(\theta_0) = 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#Statement). On the other hand, derivative of $f$ is given by

$$ f'(\theta)
= \frac{d}{d\theta} (\alpha(\theta) - x) \cdot (\alpha(\theta) - x)
= 2 \alpha'(\theta) \cdot (\alpha(\theta) - x). $$

Plugging $\theta = \theta_0$ gives

$$0 = 2\alpha'(\theta_0) \cdot (\alpha(\theta_0) - x) = 2(b-a) \cdot (p - x).$$

(Here, we used $\alpha'(\theta) = b-a $). Now this tells that $b-a$ and $p-x$ are perpendicular. Moreover, solving this equation gives

$$ \theta_0 = \frac{(a-x)\cdot(a-b)}{(a-b)\cdot(a-b)} $$

as already demonstrated by OP.

Comment: Took me a good 15 minutes to understand your solution, but it's definitely better than brute-forcing it. I like how you approached it in a different way: instead of finding the point $p$ first, you proved $b-a$ and $p-x$ are perpendicular and went from there.